# Given two intervals, how to return logical true false if intervals overlap?

Tags: time, lubridate, posixct

I'm trying to work out whether two different date ranges overlap and return a TRUE/FALSE where they do, which will allow me to successfully filter the data I'm interested in. I was trying to use lubridate intervals and the %within% which basically checks whether a date falls within a period. In the example below, I was checking whether the `started_fishing` date and the `finished_fishing` date fell within the period defined by the `start_of_fishing_season` and `end_of_fishing_season`.

This approach doesn't work. As, although in the example below the dates don't fall within the period, if we assume we are fishing constantly from the `started_fishing` date to the `finished_fishing` date then some of the dates would fall within the fishing season.

I've inserted the true/false column to indicate what a correct output should look like.

I'm guessing perhaps what I need to do is to create a sequence from `started_fishing` and `finished_fishing` and then check each date against fishing season dates? Hope this is clear enough, any help appreciated.

Ideally fixing this in lubridate (which isn't shown below) would be great.

```
deployment = data.frame(start_of_fishing_season = c(as.POSIXct("2019-10-16", tz = "UTC"),
                                                    as.POSIXct("2019-10-16", tz = "UTC")),
                        end_of_fishing_season = c(as.POSIXct("2020-05-01", tz = "UTC"),
                                                  as.POSIXct("2020-05-01", tz = "UTC")),
                        started_fishing = c(as.POSIXct("2019-06-12 15:45:00", tz = "UTC"),
                                            as.POSIXct("2019-06-12 15:45:00", tz = "UTC")),
                        finished_fishing = c(as.POSIXct("2021-03-24 15:45:00", tz = "UTC"),
                                             as.POSIXct("2019-08-13 15:45:00", tz = "UTC")),
                        fishing_overlaps = c(TRUE,FALSE))


deployment
#>   start_of_fishing_season end_of_fishing_season     started_fishing
#> 1              2019-10-16            2020-05-01 2019-06-12 15:45:00
#> 2              2019-10-16            2020-05-01 2019-06-12 15:45:00
#>      finished_fishing fishing_overlaps
#> 1 2021-03-24 15:45:00             TRUE
#> 2 2019-08-13 15:45:00            FALSE
```

Comment: I think there's an additional function in lubridate called int_overlap which does what I needed. But interested to see other approaches :)

Answer (score 0):

So, one of the ways I have found to address this problem is:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'lubridate'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     date, intersect, setdiff, union

# creating data
deployment <- data.frame(
  start_of_fishing_season = c(
    as.POSIXct("2019-10-16", tz = "UTC"),
    as.POSIXct("2019-10-16", tz = "UTC")
  ),
  end_of_fishing_season = c(
    as.POSIXct("2020-05-01", tz = "UTC"),
    as.POSIXct("2020-05-01", tz = "UTC")
  ),
  started_fishing = c(
    as.POSIXct("2019-06-12 15:45:00", tz = "UTC"),
    as.POSIXct("2019-06-12 15:45:00", tz = "UTC")
  ),
  finished_fishing = c(
    as.POSIXct("2021-03-24 15:45:00", tz = "UTC"),
    as.POSIXct("2019-08-13 15:45:00", tz = "UTC")
  )
)



# checking whether date intervals overlap
deployment <- deployment %>%
  mutate(fish_seas_int = interval(start_of_fishing_season, end_of_fishing_season)) %>%
  mutate(fishing_int = interval(started_fishing, finished_fishing)) %>%
  mutate(was_active = int_overlaps(fish_seas_int, fishing_int))


# new data
deployment
#>   start_of_fishing_season end_of_fishing_season     started_fishing
#> 1              2019-10-16            2020-05-01 2019-06-12 15:45:00
#> 2              2019-10-16            2020-05-01 2019-06-12 15:45:00
#>      finished_fishing                  fish_seas_int
#> 1 2021-03-24 15:45:00 2019-10-16 UTC--2020-05-01 UTC
#> 2 2019-08-13 15:45:00 2019-10-16 UTC--2020-05-01 UTC
#>                                        fishing_int was_active
#> 1 2019-06-12 15:45:00 UTC--2021-03-24 15:45:00 UTC       TRUE
#> 2 2019-06-12 15:45:00 UTC--2019-08-13 15:45:00 UTC      FALSE


Created on 2022-08-03 by the reprex package (v2.0.1)
```

I would be interested in alternatives...